# Probability that 2 Letters come first and last in a 15 letter sequence?

Tags: probability

Given that each, letter is picked independently and that

P(A) = 0.3

P(B) = 0.25

P(C) = 0.15

P(D) = 0.3

What is the probability that in a 15-letter sequence, "AC" comes first and last within the sequence?

Since the events are indepentdent the probability of getting AC is P(AC) = (0.3) * (0.15) = 0.045. And in a 15-letter sequence, this would look like

"AC" ...other 11 random letters... "AC".

I'm not sure how to find the probability of this specific sequence. Since there's a possibility of 11 random letters would the sample space be something like (0.3 * 0.25 * 0.15 * 0.3)^(11) since any of those are possible in 11 space ? Still not sure how to being this into one cohesive fraction probability.

Comment: Isn't it simply $0.3\cdot0.15\cdot0.3\cdot0.15$? BTW, it really doesn't matter how many letters are in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the following probabilities:

- The probability of A appearing at the first place, which is $0.3$
- The probability of C appearing at the second place, which is $0.15$
- The probability of A appearing at the one-before-last place, which is $0.3$
- The probability of C appearing at the last place, which is $0.15$

The answer is therefore $0.3\cdot0.15\cdot0.3\cdot0.15$.

BTW, the number of letters are in the sequence does not impact the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are vastly overthinking it.  We don't care about the middle letters at all.  Compute the chance that you start with $AC$, which is $0.045$ as you say, and the chance that you end with $AC$, which is also $0.045$ and multiply them because you want both.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\mathsf P(A_k\cup B_k\cup C_k\cup D_k) = 0.3+ 0.25 +0.15+ 0.3 = 1$ independently for every position.

Then the probability that the "eleven other letters" are *some* arrangement of *some* amounts of those four letters is $1^{11}$.   Hence:

$$\mathsf P(A_1,C_2, A_{14},C_{15}) ~=~ \mathsf P(A_1)\,\mathsf P(C_2)\color{gray}{\,{1}^{11}}\,\mathsf P(A_{14})\,\mathsf P(C_{15}) ~=~ (0.3\cdot 0.15)^2$$